# FBSDKShareDialog not appearing in case of video share

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-share

I am working on a project where I need to share an image and a video together on Facebook, but facing undefined behaviour.

> Issue: When I am trying to share a video using `FBSDKShareMediaContent` class (using below code), **the `FBSDKShareDialog` is not appearing**, **but it appears when I share only an image**.

My code:

```
let photo: FBSDKSharePhoto = FBSDKSharePhoto.init(image: imageToShare, userGenerated: true)

let vid: FBSDKShareVideo = FBSDKShareVideo.init(videoURL: URL(string:vidUrl!.path))

 //  FBSDKShareDialog not appearing in this case 
let shareContent: FBSDKShareMediaContent = FBSDKShareMediaContent()
shareContent.media = [photo, vid]

/*
// FBSDKShareDialog appearing 
let shareContent: FBSDKShareMediaContent = FBSDKShareMediaContent()
shareContent.media = [photo]  */


FBSDKShareDialog.show(from: self.getCurrentViewController(), with: shareContent, delegate: nil)
```

**Video URL:** file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2E0E48B7-30E5-4567-8C0B-ACAC100AE389/Documents/AppName/1499773278.555753.mp4

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution i found is, the url path i was assigning is wrong as per the [`Facebook` guidelines](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios#videos) of sharing video.

> The video URL videoURL must be an asset URL. You can get a video asset URL e.g. from UIImagePickerController.

See video sharing section inside the [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios#videos).

**UPDATE:**

**Final Solution to share image, video together using picker or document directory path whichever, this works.**

```
let shareText = "Upload video, image and text."
let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [shareText, vidUrl, imageToShare], applicationActivities: [])
present(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: I'm unclear of how this would bring up a share dialog for a video. Maybe doesn't work right with the latest SDK and Swift 4? I get no dialog, and the messages "Filtering mail sheet accounts for bundle ID" and "timed out waiting to establish a connection to the ShareUI view service extension."